# PHP and MySQL $query_run error

Tags: php

I have concern with my written code here. The connection is ok when I checked but when my if-statement here runs it goes expectedly from the password=cpassword up to the second if-statement for checking the user if exist and goes it into the else because it is false, but when it reached the third if-statement i don't know why in if($query_run) going to be false.

Therefore, the result the data hasn't added to my database and giving me an alert of ERROR which I declared in that else-statement.

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];
        if($password==$cpassword)
        {
            $query= "select * from user WHERE username ='$username'";
            $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
                {
                // there is already a user with the same username
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("user already exist.. Try another username")</script>';
                }
                else
                {
                $query = "insert into user values('$username','$password')";
                $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                if($query_run)
                {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("User Registered Go to Login page to Log in")</script>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Error..")</script>';
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Password does not match!")</script>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please, use prepared query, you are open to sql injection.

Comment: @IvanBolnikh this was not the question.

Comment: @MichaelHirschler: that does not matter. If someone is doing something unsafe, and you know it is unsafe, it is necessary to speak up.

Comment: @halfer true, in that case: please also validate $_POST* variables before using them. :-)

Comment: @Refferson Dahan just try to Echo the Query and paste in SQL.

Comment: guys, thank you so much . it really worked . my apology for being a beginner thank you again

Comment: No apologies needed for being a beginner, though it's a bit odd if several people mention your serious security problems and you ignore those messages. Do you _want_ to have security problems?

Comment: yes i just want to have that said security can somebody teach me how to code this ...actually im still in the part of fixing the connection of database and how i insert some data but ofcourse my next step is that security.. Please can i have some steps for it @halfer

Comment: Security is not something you can have steps for, it requires a fair bit of learning. I would [start here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) for SQL injection, and then [go here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database) for password storage.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```html
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];
        if($password==$cpassword)
        {
            $query= "select * from user WHERE username ='$username'";
            $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
                {
                // there is already a user with the same username
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("user already exist.. Try another username")</script>';
                }
                else
                {
                $query = "insert into user (username, password) values('$username','$password')";
                $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                if($query_run)
                {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("User Registered Go to Login page to Log in")</script>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Error..")</script>';
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Password does not match!")</script>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Change only  $query = "INSERT INTO user (username, password) VALUES ($username, $password)";

Comment: As per the other two answers (one of which has now been deleted by its author), I would like to see a mention of the security errors the OP has in their code. They are at least (1) SQL injection, and (2) plaintext password storage.

Comment: How did this solve the question? There is no specific explanation as to what was done. You're forcing people to see what the differences are in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong, there is no column specified to insert value in it.
Try this with replacing your column name:

```
$query = "insert into user (column1, column2) values('$username','$password')";
```

where `column1` and `column2` will be your `username` and `password` column.

**Note:** You are open to sql injection. So you should use prepared query.

Comment: This replicates the SQL injection vulnerability in the OP's code, as well as the plaintext password. Please **always** mention security problems when you see them!

Comment: guys, thank you so much . it really worked . my apology for being a beginner thank you again

Comment: Glad to help you @ReffersonDahan. Accept as answer if it works. :)

Comment: what do you mean accept as answer. Im just new here maybe i can help you with the points , I think.

Comment: You can click on `right` sign appearing just after `up` and `down` vote buttons to accept as answer.

Comment: @ReffersonDahan: [see this article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).